# While force stop Java FX app, deleteOnExit working or not

Tags: javafx

```
@Override //// When the main runs
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = stage;
        primaryStage.setTitle("UzPos");

        File f = new File("C:\\Windows\\checkFile");
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.createNewFile();
        } else {
            new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "App Already running", ButtonType.OK).showAndWait();
            return;
        }
        f.deleteOnExit()
}
```

This code works cool, but here is one problem. When I force stop the app from Intellij IDEA by stop button, I detected that checkfile is not deleted automatically. Is there any way to get that kind of fuction? I want to work only one instance of my app. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved single instance applications using sockets instead of files. The [code](https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-commons/blob/master/drombler-commons-client/drombler-commons-client-startup-main/src/main/java/org/drombler/commons/client/startup/main/impl/singleinstance/SingleInstanceStarter.java) is Open Source. Feel free to have a look at it.

Or consider to use [Drombler FX](https://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/), the modular application framework for JavaFX, [which provides this (optional) feature out of the box](https://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/1.0/docs/tutorial/single-instance-application.html#singleInstanceApplication).
There's also a [Getting Started](https://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/1.0/docs/tutorial/getting-started.html#gettingStarted) tutorial.